# "Can't read the url" error for angular2 dynamic components with templateUrl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-compiler

Tried to modify soultion [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009).
It works fine, but if you change template to templateUrl in component, that should load dynamically, you get an error: "No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url ...".

```
@Component({
    selector: 'string-editor',
    templateUrl: 'app/parts/string.html', //using template URL instead of inline template here
})
export class StringEditor { ... }
```

Live example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5NeUMA?p=preview). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: You are probably using `COMPILER_PROVIDERS` which has a line: `{ provide: ResourceLoader, useValue: _NO_RESOURCE_LOADER }`. [Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/compiler/src/compiler.ts#L58)

Comment: @FergalMoran see the answer below.

Comment: @MAx : can you please share your code, which you have implemented?

Comment: @SandipPatel it was the same as in accepted answer below. But it looks like in angular 2.4 Compiler was removed from exports. If you need dynamic component loading, take a look at this article https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `COMPILER_PROVIDERS`, because it overrides the `ResourceLoader`.

For dynamic loading use the `Compiler` from core package (which is actually the same as `RuntimeCompiler`):

```
@Inject(Compiler) protected compiler: Compiler
```

and add the `ApplicationModule` as import in your module:

```
imports: [ 
    ApplicationModule,
    BrowserModule,
    DynamicModule.forRoot() // singletons
],
```

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/lnPIBIRYvW46X17fvPqX/)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I solved this by implementing custom resource loader and overriding _NO_RESOURCE_LOADER like this -> providers: [ COMPILER_PROVIDERS, { provide: ResourceLoader, useValue: CustomResourceLoader }], but your solution obviously more proper.

Comment: It's not work for me, can you please help me in this case, how you have resolve it?

Comment: How to define "CustomResourceLoader "?

Comment: @cy3er : can you please help me to resolve this issue