# Angular-2 dynamic component, AOT runtime error

Tags: angular

I am implementing AOT in my angular-2 application, which load dynamic pages initially from landing page.

When it load, it throw error like below.

> No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided

[image]

**Component declaration** look like below:

```
@Component({
selector: 'page1',
templateUrl: 'Page1.html',
})
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/configs/Application.ngfactory';
import { COMPILER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/compiler';
platformBrowser(COMPILER_PROVIDERS).bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

**Note:** If i use template instead templateUrl it works, but for long HTML Template is not good

I have also tried:  ["Can't read the url" error for angular2 dynamic components with templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659389/cant-read-the-url-error-for-angular2-dynamic-components-with-templateurl)

any one has idea how to resolve this issue.